# How to retrieve projects in to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, projects

Right now im working with android/eclipse.Due to four times interruptions in power supply,i lost my whole projects what ive done so far.How to retrieve my projects into the eclipse?

Comment: you must be having the src/backup in one of your drive of your pc.import them from the specific place

Comment: @AkashG Even though if i import those folders,it showing every details but ive  used some background images for some components in my project,its not showing that background images on corresponding xml files...

Comment: you must not have saved the file after setting background and interruptions occurred.its not big deal set it again.

Comment: In Eclipse, you can right click on your project and select "Restore from Local History".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be having the src/backup in one of your drive of your pc.import them from the specific place again in your workspace of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File-> Import-> Existing project into workspace.
Select the root directory of your project. Its done :)